# Dataform: list runs in a project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dataform

I want to list runs in a given Dataform project. Currently, I can't seem to do this via the [Dataform API](https://docs.dataform.co/dataform-web/api).

Does anyone know how to list all runs for a given Dataform project?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to list BigQuery jobs using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS, look at this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs), using **user_email** equals to the service account given to the Dataform.

Other way is trigger Dataform through API and manage executions list outside Dataform.

Comment: I like the suggestion about INFORMATION_SCHEMA! Will have a look at that and see what we can learn. We currently do all of our scheduling via the Dataform UI which makes the API option a little more difficult. However, will keep that in mind, cheers